# How can I add a TextArea from a returned ArrayList to a frame?

Tags: java, awt

I am trying to return an ArrayList with two values, text and a text area. However when I press the button that is meant to do this, nothing happens. Can you please explain why this is the case?

The method that returns the ArrayList:

```
public ArrayList<Object> newFile(){
      ArrayList<Object> objectArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
      TextArea textField = new TextArea("Type File Information.., ");
      AtomicReference<String> fileText = new AtomicReference<>();


      textField.addTextListener((textListener) -> {
          fileText.set(textField.getText());
      });
      objectArrayList.add(String.valueOf(fileText));
      objectArrayList.add(textField);

      return objectArrayList;
    }
}
```

The code snippet that executes the method and gets the text area:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String action = e.getActionCommand();

        switch (action) {
            case "New":
                fileText = (String) newFile().get(0);
                MainMenu mainMenu = new MainMenu();
                mainMenu.add((TextArea)newFile().get(1));
                break;
```

The code snippet where I add the handler:

```
newFile.addActionListener(mainMenuHandler);
```

Comment: Post a proper [mre] when posting a question so we can see the full context of your problem, otherwise we are just guessing.

Comment: Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT components in favor of Swing.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using AWT. You should at least be using Swing.

```
MainMenu mainMenu = new MainMenu();
mainMenu.add((TextArea)newFile().get(1));
```

In your case you add the text area to the MainMenu, but you never add the MainMenu to the frame.

So you would need to add the "mainMenu" to the frame.

Also, when using Swing if you add a component to a visible frame then you need to invoke `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the container you add the component to.

Comment: thanks! I was just practising, should I really not use it though?

Comment: There is no reason to use AWT and Swing (although also dated) still has newer and better features than AWT.

Comment: If you're doing this for practice, I'd recommend JavaFX.